# webpack solve require arguments before build (constexpr)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm working on a RESTful API express.js server. what I expect is something like [A node Express router middleware for RESTful API base on certain folder path](https://github.com/mytharcher/rainbow). but this package using dynamic require which loads modules on runtime with an expression. this cause webpack throw an error: `Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`. what I did is change require to require.context, which introduce the actrully problem: `Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted`

sample code

```
// import-routes.js
function importRoutes(folder, pattern = /\.js$/) {
  const files = require.context(folderPath, true, pattern);
  files.keys().forEach((file) => {
    // do something here
  });
}
module.exports = (folder, pattern) => importRoutes(folder, pattern);

// index.js
const routes = require('./lib/import-api')('./apis');
// constexpr routes = require('./lib/import-api')('./apis');

// otherIndex.js
const routes = require('./lib/import-api')('./otherApis');
// constexpr routes = require('./lib/import-api')('./otherApis');
```

Is there something just like `constexpr` in cpp that could solve this on compile time?

[Reference of constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)